# Host Key Verification Failed - GitLab with Visual Studio Code on macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, macos-sierra

I keep getting a "Host Key Verification Failed" error when trying to push changes to a git controlled folder/project to Gitlab. For whatever reason, it works fine using Visual Studio for Mac, and I can login to my Gitlab account just fine via web browser.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Resolved by deleting any/all Known_hosts files in ~/.ssh/ and then executing `ssh git@gitlab.com` in Terminal and answering "yes" (which re-adds git@gitlab.com to known_hosts after re-creating a new known_hosts file).

I did some messing around in known_hosts which probably caused the problem.

Comment: I had cloned the repo in GitKraken, and then got this error when I switched over to VS Code Git. I didn't have to remove known_hosts, just `ssh git@whatever.com`. I imagine this could happen with other tools that manage credentials differently than vanilla git.

Comment: Just doing `ssh git@gitlab.com` and answering yes to save the fingerprint was enough for me, apparently that entry was just missing and VSCode doesn't add it by itself.

Comment: I had this issue after updating to the latest version of macOS Monterey and this solution resolved it.

Comment: I just navigated to my folder and performed a git pull origin main.  Clicked yes to the authenticity prompt and was able to use source control in vs code without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, I was receiving this error from Git on MS Visual Studio Code.

I had to launch it from Git Bash to pull in my git and ssh environment configuration.

```
<your git bash prompt> $ Code
```

VS Code should Launch, and you should be able to clone a repo via ssh then.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my home profile was loading as "P:\" in git bash (because of my work's IT team...).

Ensure that in git bash you have generated an ssh key using `ssh-keygen` and that GitLab knows about the key.

If you still have the issue, run `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <gitlab-host> uptime` to make gitlab trusted.

Answer (score 0):

I re-created ssh keys in git for Windows and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with known_hosts file only. I already had an entry for the remote server in this file. After deleting existing entry for the remote server I was able to follow the steps to login to remote server and then add a new entry for same in known_hosts file.